Tailwindcss beta 1 postcss gulp not working
I'm trying to construct the simplest possible Tailwindcss 4 Beta 1 postcss gulp pipeline. It runs with no error, but no css file is outputted to the dest directory.
My gulp.js file:
const
    { src, dest, watch, series } = require('gulp')
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss')
    sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
    tailwindcss = require('@tailwindcss/postcss')

function cssTask() {
    return src('./src/**/*.{css}')
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init() )
        .pipe( postcss([ tailwindcss ]) )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.write('.') )
        .pipe( dest('./dest/css') )
}


exports.default = series(
    cssTask,
)

my postcss.config.mjs file (taken directly from Tailwindcss 4 Beta 1 docs):
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        '@tailwindcss/postcss': {},
    ]
}

My tailwind.config.ts file:
module.exports = {
    content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}"],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}

My src/app.css file:
@import "tailwindcss";

My src/html/index.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Tailwind Starter 2022</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dest/css/app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="bg-gray-800 py-12 px-4 m-20 border-4 border-blue-700">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <h1 class="text-4xl text-blue-600 font-bold mb-6">
          Hello Tailwind CSS!
        </h1>
        <a
          class="
            py-2
            px-4
            bg-blue-600
            hover:bg-blue-500
            text-white
            rounded-md
            shadow-md
            transition-colors
            duration-200
          "
          href="#"
          >EXPLORE &rarr;</a
        >
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>

My gulp:
CLI version: 3.0.0
Local version: 5.0.0

So what am I doing wrong? ;)
